# How to proceed when testin for non-linear relationships between variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, multivariate-analysis, pandas

I'm trying to predict the amount of money a customer spends on a product by using linear regression.

I had the hypothesis that there was a non-linear connection between the Product_Category, the occupation and the Gender of the buyer.

I'm new to data analysis, therefore my logic may be quite wrong, but what I did was, to calculate the mean of the purchasing amount and then find the mean for every combination of Category_Occupation_Gender and whenever there was a deviation of at least 20% with the overall mean, I included the combination as an independent variable.

When I ran the regression, most of the variables seem to have an extremely low p-values (exp of variable - Category1_Occupation_3_Gender_1), but some of them have p-values of 0.30 and above.

As someone just starting at that field, is my logic for checking the non-linear relationship between variables making sense, and if it's how should I be proceeding from there. Do I keep only the statistically valid variables or as most of them seem to be a good predictor, I keep all of them.

I'm using Python(Pandas, Numpy) and Excel for the analysis.

Comment: You have several questions packed into this one post (how to select predictor variables, how to test non-linear relationships (in your case, it's not clear why you are looking to test relationships between predictors, rather than between your outcome variable (purchasing amount) and each of the predictors)).  You should separate them into separate posts.

Comment: Please consult these guidelines for writing a good question on this site: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1479/241093